# org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.registerFilter is gone in 5.6.8

Tags: elasticsearch

I am upgrading plugins to Elasticsearch 5.6.8 that we wrote when ES was 2.4.2 and later upgraded to 5.1.2

In 5.6.8 RestController.registerFilter method has been removed. What is the workaround?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/22367#issuecomment-270141480) comment. It explains a little bit why `RestController#registerFilter` method was removed and what a workaround looks like.